# Transfer WhatsApp conversations to iOS

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, data-transfer, ios

Is there any way to transfer WhatsApp conversations from an Android 6 device to an iOS 9 device? I have already tried to use the software by iPhone-to-PC unsuccessfully (could not read conversations from an Android device)

Comment: Related on SoftwareRecs.SE: [Transfering Whatsapp data to an iOS mobile](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/85051/520)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a backup and upload it to Google Drive to restore it later with the other device.

I have no Apple device but I guess that synonymous there a backup from Google Drive can be restored.

Comment: This definitely does **NOT** work.  Ios will not be able to read and restore the WhatsApp backup on Google Drive as they use different encryption protocols.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [WhatsApp Transfer](http://www.backuptrans.com/android-whatsapp-transfer.html), free software but only usable for three devices.

- Make sure you have the latest version of Whatsapp on both devices and the last of iTunes on the pc.
- On Android activate *debug usb*: **Settings**-> **Device Info** and clicks 7 times on **Version Build**.In the Settings menu there will be *Developer Options* where there will be the usb *Debug Option*.
- Connect both devices to pc and open Whatsapp Transfer
- On the Android you will appear to backup, you allow but without entering the password.
- You will now have all your messages/conversations and in the left column the device you want to display.
- Right-click on your Android device.
- Click on the *"transfer messages from android to iphone"* and close Whatsapp on your iPhone.
- Finally select the iPhone and click on confirm.